# how does promise work in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, queue, promise, q

so I am using the latest version of angular,

I've written code like this

```
$q.all({
  a: $q.then(func1, failHandler),
  b: $q.then(func2, failHandler),
  c: $q.then(func3, failHandler),
}).then(func4);
```

would the execution always guarantee to be func1, func2, func3, func4?

cuz I get func4 firing before the other three. which brings up another question.

does `$q.then(callbacks).then` always fire the callbacks before firing the next then?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  `.all()` is not meant for sequential operations - it's meant for parallel operations.

Comment: Please show us the source code of `funk1` `funk2` and `func3`. This code is also full of incorrect syntax - namely `$q` does not expose a `.then` method (did you mean `.when`?

Comment: ... $q.all({}) spits out a promise, does it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**

None of the examples below are suggested to be used in a real appliation, nor it is the best practice or anything. Actually, some of them are [The Deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern). I just want to demonstrate how it work.

To answer your question, lets do some experiments on it first.

**Given callbacks like these:**

```
function okHandler(value) {
  console.log(value + ' has been called.');
  return value;
}

function doneHandler(values) {
  console.log('Done! : ' + JSON.stringify(values));
}

function delayed(value, delay) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $timeout(function () {
    deferred.resolve(value);
  }, delay);

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

**Parallel:**

```
$q.all({
  a: $q.when('a').then(okHandler),
  b: $q.when('b').then(okHandler),
  c: $q.when('c').then(okHandler),
}).then(doneHandler);
```

Result:

```
a has been called.
b has been called.
c has been called.
Done! : {"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c"}
```

**Parallel with a delay simulation:**

```
$q.all({
  a: delayed('da', 200).then(okHandler),
  b: delayed('db', 100).then(okHandler),
  c: delayed('dc', 300).then(okHandler),
}).then(doneHandler);
```

Result:

```
db has been called.
da has been called.
dc has been called.
Done! : {"b":"db","a":"da","c":"dc"}
```

**Sequential:**

```
delayed('sa', 400).then(okHandler).then(function () {
  delayed('sb', 100).then(okHandler).then(function () {
    delayed('sc', 10).then(okHandler).then(doneHandler);
  })
});
```

Result:

```
sa has been called.
sb has been called.
sc has been called.
Done! : "sc"
```

**Sequential alternative style:**

```
delayed('ssa', 600)
  .then(okHandler)
  .then(delayed.bind(null, 'ssb', 100))
  .then(okHandler)
  .then(delayed.bind(null, 'ssc', 10))
  .then(okHandler)
  .then(doneHandler);
```

Result:

```
ssa has been called.
ssb has been called.
ssc has been called.
Done! : "ssc"
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/dNZ8koAS4G6fNmahfmj6?p=preview

Now lets see at your questions.

Q: would the execution always guarantee to be `func1`, `func2`, `func3`, `func4`?

A: No, only `func4` is guaranteed to be executed last. `func1`, `func2` and `func3` can be executed in any order.

Q: Does `$q.then(callbacks).then` always fire the callbacks before firing the next then?

A: Yes!

Comment: -1 while it looks like you put a lot of effort into this answer (and that's great, thanks) it contains several inaccuracies that are hard to overlook. Namely the deferred anti pattern in the first example and the following example that shows nothing (the execution order there is not _really_ guaranteed). The "sequential" version has (needless) nesting for some reason, etc. Fix those issues and I'll gladly remove my down vote.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for the comment. But I didn't say that any of the above examples should be used, nor it is the best practice or anything. And I've actually learned from you about the [The Deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern). I just want to demonstrate how those examples work (sorry if I haven't done it well) and answer the OP's specific questions.

Comment: By including them in an answer on Stack Overflow and not warning about it - they _will_ be used and people _will_ consider them best practice :) If you could fix those issues that would be awesome.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Run out of time today. I've included a disclaimer at the top, will try to fix those issues tomorrow. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

You need to distinguish beteen *promises* and *Q*.

Promises are a high-level construct that have a `then` property.

Try `$q.defer()` and don't forget to resolve it.

Comment: I think I understand promises and I have no idea what you've just written. Please consider rephrasing it.